# Sorting English, Greek and math variables in excel: English (Capital, lower), Greek (Capital, lower), math

Tags: excel, sorting

I have a list of capital and lowercase English, Greek, and math symbols I am using for a paper. I'm not sure how to sort these correctly so I tried to use the default sorting in Excel but I don't like the output. I would like to sort them in the following order.

1. Capital English
2. lowercase English
3. Capital Greek
4. lowercase Greek
5. math

When I sorted them I got this.

1. math
2. Mixed Capital and lowercase English (caps first)
3. Mixed Capital and lowercase Greek (caps first)

Pre-sorted: (the way I am thinking it should be)

[image: Pre-sorted]

Post-sorted:

[image]

Is there a way to make a custom sort to do this? I see that there is an option to do a custom sort but I'm not sure how to apply it.

Comment: What happens if you sort in Word?

Comment: My document crashes each time so I'm not sure.

Comment: Try a new document just with that list of characters without any other text.

Comment: It doesn't crash now but I get the same result as in Excel